# QWidget::grab function for videos: cannot catch

Tags: c++, qt, video-capture

I want to save the current window to an image (like as ATL+PrintScreen) in Qt. Example, for the [Qt Media Player Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-player-example.html) (you can get all the code in Qt Creator examples when search "player", I added this code to `player.h` :

```
//private slots:
...
void exportVideoToImages();
```

and in `player.cpp`:

```
void Player::exportVideoToImages()
{
    qDebug() << "ok";
    QPixmap const& px = grab();
    px.save("File.png");
}
```

Add this line to the the constructor to trigger the slot:

```
new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_G), this, SLOT(exportVideoToImages()));
```

So, when I trigger CTRL+G, I will receive an image "File.png". It worked, but the problem is the playing video cannot be catch.

This is the two images, one from Alt+PrintScreen and one from the program:
[image: from Alt+PrintScreen]

[image: from the program]

Why is it? How can I grab the video in Qt? Can you show me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
if (screen) {
    QPixmap px =screen->grabWindow(this->winId());
    px.save("screen.png");
}
```

[image]